tkinter entry windows not working properly in oop
I've got a method of a class that is used to register the user, and has some tkinter entry with:
email=tk.StringVar()
nameent = tk.Entry(registerwindow,textvariable = email, font=('Arial',14,'normal'))

but when I try to get the value that has been inputted in the name entry it returns a blank result
I've tried getting it to output the entry value at multiple stages in the user registration process to see where it was erroring but I found that it doesn't even seem that it picks up the value from the entry from the beginning

Most probably you have created more than one instance of Tk().

Please [edit] your question to provide a complete [mre], otherwise it's difficult for us to diagnose what might be happening.

It could be that email is a local variable that is getting destroyed by the garbage collector. Without a proper [mcve] it's impossible for us to say for sure.

I assume that you want to use the user entered email. For instance, you may want to validate the email with a function or check whether email exists in the database. In that case, you don't need to declare a StringVar. By using nameent.get(), you'll get the user entered email which you can use it in a function. For the sake of simplicity I've given my example without class which you can convert into class and function.
import tkinter as tk

def get_email():
    email = nameent.get()
    print(email)
    
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")

registerwindow= tk.Frame(root)
registerwindow.pack()

nameent = tk.Entry(registerwindow,font=('Arial',14,'normal'))
nameent.pack()

btn = tk.Button(registerwindow, text = "Get Email", command = get_email)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()

